# c++ array and if statement not working

Tags: c++

Simple code storing user input into array and displaying it.
If one of the elements of array is 4 then it should print "four" on the screen. But problem is even if there are no number 4 in array it always prints four.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;


int main (){

    int x[10];
    int n;
    cin>>n;

    for(int i=1;i<=n;i++){
    cin>>x[i] ;       


    }
    cout<<endl;
       for(int i=1;i<=n;i++){
    if (x[i]=4) 
    cout<<"four"<<endl;
    else continue;     


    }


    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: you have an off-by-one bug in your program, arrays in C/C++ are zero-based. Either allocate an array of size 11 or index starting from 0.

Answer (score 5):

`if (x[i]=4)` assigns 4 to `x[i]`.

You want to use `==` in order to compare.

Note that the expression of the assignment returns the **assigned value**, in this case `if (x[i]=4)` will be evaluated **always** to true.

A tip for life: Enable compiler warnings.

---

Another thing that you should take care of is your `for` loop:

`for(int i=1;i<=n;i++)`

Remember that arrays are *zero-based* in C++ (and most languages). 
If you have an array of size `N`, then the indexes are from `0` to `N-1` (`N` in total).

So you need to do:

`for(int i=0;i<n;i++)`

Answer (score 2):

You must use `==` instead of `=`:

```
if (x[i]==4)
```

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple of issues that stand out, the first which is your main question is that you are using assignment(`=`) instead of logical equals(`==`) here:

```
if (x[i]=4) 
        ^
```

should be:

```
if (x[i]==4) 
        ^^
```

Enabling warnings probably would have helped you catch this one on your own, for example in `gcc` using `-W -Wall` would have given you a warning like this:

```
warning: suggest parentheses around assignment used as truth value [-Wparentheses]
```

Your `for` loops also looks odd:

```
for(int i=1;i<=n;i++)
          ^  ^^
```

Arrays in C++ start at index `0` not `1`, you are also not doing any bounds checking to insure that `n` does not lead you outside the array bounds, which is [`undefined behavior`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). Usually since arrays start at zero `<` is used for the ending condition. In this specific case if you array has `10` elements you would use `i<10`.

Answer (score 1):

```
if (x[i]=4)
```

This line doesn't check for equality between `x[i]`  and 4. It actually assigns 4 to `x[i]` in the if statement and then check if the result of this assignement is actually equivalent to `true`.

You need to use the correct comparison operator :

```
if (x[i] == 4)
         ^^
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a common mistake, which normally is ignored by compiler. You used assignment in if statement:

```
if(x[i]=4)
```

not comparison:

```
if(x[i]==4).
```

Mistakes like this can be easily removed by using Yoda conditions and writing your if statements having r-value (here it's your "4") on the left side, like:

```
if(4==x[i])
```

which in case of misspelling will result in compilation error (and you will be forced to recheck it). 
So something like

```
if(4=x[i])
```

will not compile.

(Or enable option to treat warnings like errors)